# Converting SQL FLOAT to SQL INT, lost data

Tags: sql, casting, floating-point, integer

I'm having some problems with converting some data stored in a FLOAT datatype to data stored in an INT datatype. The below example illustrates my problem:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE
(
 id INT,
 weight FLOAT
)
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(1,0.015662)

SELECT CAST(weight * 1000000 AS INT) FROM @data
SELECT 0.015662 * 1000000
SELECT CAST(0.015662 * 1000000 AS INT)
```

The desired results would be: `ID = 1 VALUE = 15662`
However when coming from the `@data` table, I don't seem to get this. I instead get `ID = 1 VALUE = 15661.`

Does anyone have any idea why this is? I'm guessing it's some sort of float nuance. But I never thought it would have a problem with something like the above. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the classic [(int)((0.1+0.7)*10)](http://codepad.org/dqFiAB9Z) problem. Because floats have arbitrary precision some data loss when casting to int is possible even for very simple cases.

Use `ROUND(weight * 1000000.0, 0)` instead.

Comment: ROUND(weight * 1000000.0, 0) would be better because we don't know which system author uses.

Answer (score 0):

This is common behaviour for float data type due to specificity of float on computers.
Use decimal (number) data type with fixed digits after decimal point. For example, decimal(10, 6).