# Access SQL INT function

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm trying to extract some numbers with decimals but need to remove the decimal part. There's no fixed length on any of both sides.

I have already tried:

```
INT()
INTR()
ROUND()
```

Usually `INT()` should solve this but sometimes it doesn't return the correct number (for example, `INT(3)` returns `2`).

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example of INT(3) returns 2?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the function `TRUNC(number, [, decimal_places])` ?

**EDIT**

For the round precision you can see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398700/converting-sql-float-to-sql-int-lost-data#4398733)

Comment: Yeah I tried, but an error telling me that the function is not defined within the expression pops up.

Comment: You could try : `ROUND(column_name * 1000000, 0)` like the link I updated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it on my own! ROUND didn't work and FLOOR was also undefined...

I ended up needing to use two INTs with a FORMAT in one of them.

Thank you anyway.