# Why would someone store a DECIMAL as an INT in a SQL Server database and then do the math in the software?

Tags: sql-server, database, sqldatatypes

I ran into a database where I was looking for a particular value to `SUM`... in this case it was **distance in miles**. I had a hell of a time using my "search all values in database" procedure to find how the frontend displayed value was stored in the backend database.

That's until I realized they stored **miles** as an `integer` and displayed it as a `decimal`.

For instance:

- Distance in DB: 2368 (as an `INT`)
- Distance in Frontend: 23.68

Why would someone do this? Is there some sort of performance advantage?

Edit: Also, this is a major globally used piece of software used for delivery routing... so I'm wondering if they know something I don't.

Another note... they do store other values as `FLOAT` with the same exact 2-point precision they are displaying distance as.

Comment: I think the more relevant question is not about `int` vs `float` but `int` vs `decimal`. And I can't imagine a GREAT reason why you would do this. Maybe to save a byte or two per record (Assuming here though).

Comment: Most likely whoever wrote the code was confused about floats, database types, and/or using a language that didn't support decimals. In all databases except SQLite the `NUMERIC(s,p)` or equivalent type is used to specify how big a number can be and how many decimals it is allowed to have *without* loss of precision. If someone uses eg Javascript though, which has no decimal type, or uses string concatenation to pass parameters as floats instead of decimals, he/she may think that databases can lose precision

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is an industry-specific software that was created by and is used by a $200+ billion dollar company globally... which is why I'm taken back a bit and figured there must be something I don't know.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit on the backend software? What language is it? What numeric representation format is it using? etc.

Comment: @justiceorjustus Unicenter TNG perhaps? Or something similar? Older software was made to work with *any* database, even those that didn't have datetime or decimal types. That's why you may see integers used instead of decimals or dates. There are worse cases, like [zoned decimals](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzasd/zodecfo.htm) - using a letter as the last digit to signify both precision and the sign of the number. That's still used by IATA files to report ticket sales between airlines.

Comment: @justiceorjustus in fact using a 32-bit "unix timestamps" to store dates is going to cause [a bit of a problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) in a few years, as using 1970 as a base means there will be an overflow by 2038

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The software is by Omnitracs and it is used by a major beverage distributor that I work for (including many more companies).  Weird thing is... it uses `FLOAT` for other things that are displayed even on the same panel... such as delivery volumes. Displayed in the same 2-point precision, as well.

Comment: @justiceorjustus something tells me the software also runs on AS/400 ...

Comment: Size would be a reason.  Buy disk and memory is cheap.

Comment: The real answer? Whoever wrote this probably never thought the miles would be used with decimals. Probably many years ago. Then someone working on the front end said "Hey we need more precision, let's start storing the value with decimals too." Now it's ingrained in every aspect of the software and it would be a huge undertaking to change so they just roll with it. Pretty much how every weird database or software spaghetti was created ever.

Comment: Maybe they're storing hundredths of miles. And use an integer routing algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FLOAT` is terrible because it has precision and conversion issues, but I think you're more focused on why `INT` was used instead of `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`

There are a few possible reasons I can think of:

1. `INT` is (negligibly) smaller:

   - `DECIMAL` and `NUMERIC` are `5-17 bytes` depending on precision
   - `INT` is `4 bytes`
2. Some people believe `INT` is faster, but good luck proving that
3. You mention this is used globally, so it may make more sense for the format of a decimal value to be handled by the front end anyway.  For instance, `12.89` in the US is `12,89` in many European countries.

Comment: I started writing about decimals having no format, but googling for `Omnitracs` and AS400 return a few hits. Data on AS440/ DB2 can be stored as flat files and queried either as a delimited file (often using COBOL) or SQL over DB2. Field sizes and separators *do* play a role there and quite often the number of decimals is part of the field definition, not the actual value.

Comment: I'm going to rule out 3 because they do store decimal values (same precision) as `float` for other things... still... not sure if 1 or 2 is enough to convince me that's why they did it.

Comment: @justiceorjustus I did encounter such unexpected data when pulling data from DB2 on AS400 as files a decade ago. The data may be stored this way to avoid rewriting code for different databases, even though most databases support precise decimals nowadays

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So are you saying you think they just updated old legacy code to make the current software? Because still, like I said, they are using `float` for hundreds of other columns.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the comments - one billing system I work with is in DB2 on an AS400 and often have it in mind (mostly against my will)

Comment: I'm going to take this as the most logical explanation, I guess. The world may never know.

Answer (score -1):

With floats it is possible to lose some data when casting. You will end up with unexpected results. See: [Converting SQL FLOAT to SQL INT, lost data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398700/converting-sql-float-to-sql-int-lost-data)

Comment: Which is why everyone uses `NUMERIC(s,p)` instead of FLOAT. Never integer with unspecified decimals. Quite likely whoever wrote the codd didn't understand the difference and/or used a language that didn't support decimals, like Javascript